# Access files using using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios5, cordova

I'm trying to work with files on IOS, using Phonegap[cordova 1.7.0]. 
I read how to access files and read them on the [API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) of phone gap. But I don't know, when the file is read where will it be written ? & How can I output the text, image, or whatever the text is containing on the iPhone screen?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what worked for me in case anyone needs it:

```
function ReadFile() {
  var onSuccess = function (fileEntry) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
      console.log("read success");
      console.log(evt.target.result);
      document.getElementById('file_status').innerHTML = evt.target.result;
    };
    reader.onerror = function (evt) {
      console.log("read error");
      console.log(evt.target.result);
      document.getElementById('file_status').innerHTML = "read error: " + evt.target.error;
    };

    reader.readAsText(fileEntry); // Use reader.readAsURL to read it as a link not text.
  };

  console.log("Start getting entry");
  getEntry(true, onSuccess, { create: false });
};
```

Comment: @john_cat & oasisweng: I've added a comment with an example that I think addresses your question. HTH!

Comment: this is not working for me. Can you please let me know which version of phonegap should I use in order to run this source code?

Answer (score 5):

As of Cordova 3.5 (at least), `FileReader` objects only accept `File` objects, not `FileEntry` objects (I'm not sure about prior releases).

Here's an example that will output the contents a local file `readme.txt` to the console. The difference here from Sana's example is the call to `FileEntry.file(...)`. This will provide the `File` object needed for the call to the `FileReader.readAs` functions.

```
function readFile() {
    window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile('readme.txt', 
            {create: false, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                    var reader = new window.FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {console.log(evt.target.result);};
                    reader.onerror = function(evt) {console.log(evt.target.result);};
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                }, function(e){console.log(e);});
            }, function(e){console.log(e);});
    }, function(e) {console.log(e);});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using phonegap(Cordova) 1.7.0, following page will work in iOS, replace following template in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileWriter Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
            writer.truncate(11);  
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
                writer.seek(4);
                writer.write(" different text");
                writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                    console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
                }
            };
        };
        writer.write("some sample text");
    }
    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Write File</p>
  </body>
</html>
```