# File Format for Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, json, cordova, string-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access files using using Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461680/access-files-using-using-phonegap)

When I read data from files on IOS5 using phone gap[cordova 1.7.0], the output is **object object**. How can I modify it to be read as a normal string?

Comment: is it the output? i mean "object object"

Comment: what data is in file and what out put is show and what do u want to display it as?

Comment: The data in the file is: Line1. Line2. Line3
The output date is: object object. 
I want it to be displayed normally: Line 1, .... & so on.

Comment: put it here in comment or question

Comment: or give it me on skype: the_saad1

Comment: Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/OnlyHope/BbWkE/ Sorry for being late

Comment: I run this code on IOS5 using Phonegap 7

Comment: tell me lines where u'r print the output

Comment: I put the displaying function alone here http://jsfiddle.net/OnlyHope/3EkWX/ to be easy to check it.

Comment: i'm really sorry i got 2 go in emergency, will be be back in 2,3 hrs or may b long. you may wait or check me on skype if i available, and the thing i 'm getiin ghere that you are passing the object as it is or adding object to it not the objects string, like if we have a lable, then u r adding lable to the file not the lable.text