# Download and save a pdf file from my html5 based app and saving it to iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I'm creating a html5 based app for iPhone.My question is in my server i'm having some pdf files.When i'm clicking the download button the pdf file is viewing but there is no way to go to back page at that time and not saving pdf file in iPhone.Just i want to download a file and save it to iPhone.Is it is possible saving a file in iPhone.suggest me something.

Comment: its is possible to store in iphone. But you have to use Hybrid app concept.Are you using phonegap ???

Comment: Ya i'm using phone-gap what is hybrid app. Thank u for u'r response.

Answer (score 0):

Try with FILE Read & write opertaion here [the link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) in phonegap

EDIT

Try to create a plugin ,Search the plugin creation and use the following native code

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:@"/MYFOLDER"];
NSArray *pdfList = [list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.pdf'"]];
NSLog(@"%@", pdfList);
```

Comment: i'm using force download attribute in html5. The thing is the pdf file is viewing in my iPhone but how to save it in my iPhone.Thank u for u'r valuable response.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461680/access-files-using-using-phonegap

Comment: Hi Fazil i downloaded and saving files in document directory.Now my question is how to read files from document directory and how to display in my app.

Comment: It's a html app. how can i add this objective-c code. Another thing is i'm getting docx files not the pdf files.can u help me from this plsss

Comment: @harish for calling the above you should check how to used hybrid app methods

Comment: can u provide some links about that hybrid apps